# how to get export wallet from remix JS vm ethereum?

Tags: private-key, ethereum, remix

When using Etherum [remix](http://remix.ethereum.org/) to develop smart contract, they have 5 accounts.

How can I export them, or get private key?

Comment: Why would you want to? They don't exist outside of the Remix sandbox. If you need to use accounts in another environment, you should switch the environment to "Injected Web3" (ie, Metamask) or "Web3 Provider" (ie, TestRPC)

Comment: well, I really like the icon of the address that in the remix JS vm, so I want to export it, but thanks anyway! @Adam